# Cannot Install Phusion Passenger 3.0.13 with Nginx 1.2.1

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

I installed gem Passenger which installed 3.0.13.  Then I executed passenger-install-nginx-module which is what the Nginx instructions on http://www.modrails.com said to do.  It installs the latest stable version which is 1.2.1 according to the Nginx official wiki page.  I said to install Nginx to /usr/local/nginx (which is the default if you go to the nginx wiki website).  I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pcre_free_study", referenced from:
      _ngx_pcre_free_studies in ngx_regex.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make: *** [build] Error 2
--------------------------------------------

It looks like something went wrong

Please read our Users guide for troubleshooting tips:

   /Users/server1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd3.2.3/gems/passenger-3.0.13/doc/Users guide Nginx.html

If that doesn't help, please use our support facilities at:

   http://www.modrails.com/

We'll do our best to help you.
```

I have done searches for several hours trying to find a resolution.  I tried the Google Group for Phusion Passenger but did not find anything.  I do not know if there is a mismatch in version numbers or not.  The documentation says nothing about this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, saw this question but posted on StackOverflow.

Check out my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065037/passenger-nginx-module-failing/11067526#11067526

From SO:

I see NGINX has a [ticket](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/94#comment:9) for this that has been closed, but the solution did not work for me.

I did, however, get NGINX up and running again with Passenger by running a customized installation. It's obviously a compatibility issue with versions 2 and up.

First I just pulled down the NGINX source (1.0.15).

In my /usr/local

```
wget http://www.nginx.org/download/nginx-1.0.15.tar.gz nginx_source
```

Untar

```
 tar -xvz nginx-1.0.15.tar.gz
```

Then run the passenger installation. Choosing option 2 (Customized Instalation)

```
sudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

There it prompts for where the source is `/usr/local/nginx-1.0.15` and where you want it installed `/usr/local/nginx` (in my case).

Everything worked fine from there, anyone know of any real fixed for NGINX 2, please let me know.

Comment: I was able to get Nginx installed with no errors!!  I saw the ticket that was opened and could not get it working either.  This is why I submitted this question.  I just have another question.  I still have Apache pointing to port 80.  I would like to point Nginx to 8080 or another port for now.  Can I put the listen statement at the http level of the config file or can I just do listen at the server statement level?   My plans are to eventually switch all our websites to Nginx.

Comment: Yeah just change the listen line in the server block.

Wherever you installed nginx, open conf/nginx.conf and change `listen 80;` to `listen 8080;`